Equivalent Fractions and common denominator
Just a math student with a question about this problem.
$$
\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}+\frac{1}{x^{2/3}} 
$$
To get the denominators to be the same, can I just put the whole first fraction to the power of 2?
$$
(\frac{1}{x^{1/3}})^2+\frac{1}{x^{2/3}} 
$$
Mathway says this won't work and I need to multiply the first fraction by
$$
(\frac{1}{x^{1/3}})(\frac{x^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}})+\frac{1}{x^{2/3}} 
$$
but I don't see what is wrong in raising the first fraction to 2 to get the same denominator,
Thank you!!!!

You can't multiply a term only in the denominator. You have to multiply that term both in the denominator and the numerator

Is $3+5$ the same as $3^2+5$?

You may do what you did if $\frac{1}{x^{1/3}} = \left(\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\right)^2$

When you are aiming for a common denominator, it is important that whatever manipulation you do doesn't change the value of the thing you're doing.
When you square the term $\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}$, you're making it different - for example, if $x = 8$ then $\frac{1}{8^{1/3}} = \frac{1}{2}$ but $\left(\frac{1}{8^{1/3}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$. On the other hand, if you multiply by $\frac{x^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}$ then you are multiplying everything by 1, and multiplying by 1 does not change the value of anything.

Alternative approach:
Let $~y = x^{1/3}.$
Then, you are evaluating
$$\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{y}{y^2} + \frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{y + 1}{y^2} = \frac{x^{1/3} + 1}{x^{2/3}}.$$
An alternative approach is that you are evaluating
$$\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{y^2}{y^3} + \frac{y}{y^3} = \frac{y^2 + y}{y^3} = \frac{x^{2/3} + x^{1/3}}{x}.$$

In the first example above, you had
$$\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{y} \times \frac{y}{y} = \frac{y}{y^2},$$
which is valid whenever $~y \neq 0.~$
That is, since $~\dfrac{y}{y} = 1,~$ I can multipy $~\dfrac{1}{y}~$ by $~\dfrac{y}{y},~$ without changing the value of $~\dfrac{1}{y}.$

I used the substitution $~y = x^{1/3},~$ because I thought that the concept would then be easier to grasp.
